# If Then statement not working in VBS for a CSV file

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I'm attempting to create an easy script for my co-workers and I to check CSV files for certain items (ID number and Attendance points) quicker than manually opening up them up into Excel, scanning over 100 or so rows and then re-exporting as CSV (when you have to do this multiple times a day the time required starts to add up). To get started I created the first part to just check if the attendance points are greater than what would be allowed and then throwing an error and letting us know to go in and fix it. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it working...

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim ws
Set ws = ActiveSheet.Range("S11, S200")
If ws > 28 Then
  MsgBox "Error: User with more than 28 presence checks!"
ElseIf ws > 14 Then
  MsgBox "Error: User with more than 14 presence checks!"
ElseIf ws > 12 Then
  MsgBox "Error: User with more than 12 presence checks!"
ElseIf ws > 8 Then
  MsgBox "Error: User with more than 8 presence checks!"
ElseIf ws > 4 Then
  MsgBox "Error: User with more than 4 presence checks!"
End If
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What error are you getting and on what line?

Comment: Line 4, Char 1.
Object required: 'ActiveSheet'
Code: 800A01A8

Comment: It seems like your missing some code here. Shouldnt you be telling the compiler where to get the fil to open in the first place?

Comment: It's supposed to be a simple Drag and drop and run, unfortunately i'm a bit of a novice..

Answer (score 0):

This runs for me, although quite painfully slow.

Things i noticed -

- you never told it where the file was. Even with a drag and drop feature you still have to know where to look for whatever.
- You messing with late binding, but dont set the ws.Range properly. I just used the cells property as setting ws.Range might look confusing at first.

  Private Sub scoob()

  ```
  Dim oExcel
  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  oExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop\Book3.csv")
  Dim ws
  Set ws = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
  If ws > 28 Then
    MsgBox "Error: User with more than 28 presence checks!"
  ElseIf ws > 14 Then
    MsgBox "Error: User with more than 14 presence checks!"
  ElseIf ws > 12 Then
    MsgBox "Error: User with more than 12 presence checks!"
  ElseIf ws > 8 Then
    MsgBox "Error: User with more than 8 presence checks!"
  ElseIf ws > 4 Then
    MsgBox "Error: User with more than 4 presence checks!"
  End If
  ```

  End Sub

Answer (score 0):

VBScript doesn't support implicit objects like VBA, so you can't use `ActiveSheet` directly. You need explicit handles to your objects. In this case you access the active sheet via the application object. Also, `.Range("S11, S200")` is not going to work. Range strings are defined with colons. Try something like this:

```
Set ws  = oExcel.ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("S11:S200")
```

For more information about translating VBA to VBScript see [my blog](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml).

For further help with your current code (I doubt that `rng > 28`, etc. is going to work the way you seem to expect) post a new question with more information about your input data.

---

As an alternative, since your input file appears to be a CSV, you could process the file as a text file:

```
filename  = "C:\path\to\your.csv"
delimiter = ","

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
csv = fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll

rows = Split(csv, vbNewLine)
For Each row In rows
  fields = Split(row, delimiter)
  For Each field In fields
    'do stuff
  Next
Next
```